# Update downloader with silent Version check -> Error opening media file

Tags: java, install4j

We use the install4j "Update downloader with silent Version check" to periodically update our application installer.

With the introduction of the "Update downloader with silent Version check", we have noticed two problems from the Users.

1. Error opening media file as can be seen in the screenshot. The Media file is the file that is downloaded in the 1st Step of the updater. Screenshot below

[image]

The error log file mentions

[0:918] extracting files
[0:932] Included files: 16
[3:537] ERROR: Could not open FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF 32 C:\Users\ttttttttt\Downloads\xxxxxxxxxx_7_xxxx_yy_zz_64Bit.exe
[128:104] emptying C:\Users\ttttttttt\AppData\Local\Temp\e4j8A6C.tmp_dir1662356615

The Users have not opened the downloaded file. Normally clickin on OK and a retry generally works.

2. The second problem some users are facing

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The 2nd error mentions that the bgupdater.exe is already running. Even here, clicking on "Wiederholen" generally works and the update proceeds.

What we do not understand is that why these errors arise. A retry proceeds without errors in all cases normally.

The application uses install4j version 8 and java 1.8
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jVl3I.png

Comment: On stackoverflow you cannot ask two questions in a single post. Also, for these kinds of issues, please contact support@ej-technolgies.com.

Comment: I will to further follow up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem looks like anti-virus software problem where the anti-virus software detects a .exe file that is extracted to the %TEMP% directory and immediately quarantines it.

For the second problem, please locate the log file of the running bgupdater process which is located in the %TEMP% directory. Either you start the bgupdater process too frequently or it is hanging somewhere, you would need to find that out. To install a new version, all executables of the installation must be closed.